# Elegant way to read emacs org-mode tables into a python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, emacs, org-mode

When working with python pandas I often like to create tables with emacs org-mode. To read the table I do something like

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import *

D = pd.read_csv('file.dat',sep='|')
D = D.drop(D.columns[0], axis=1)
D = D.drop(D.columns[-1], axis=1)
D = D.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())
```

Is there a more elegant (in particular shorter) way to read the org-mode table into a pandas dataframe? Maybe there is also an elegant way to keep table and python source in the same org-file.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have the table *and* the  source block to process it in the Org mode file? No need for an interrmediate CSV file. At least of simple things and experimentation, it's pretty convenient.

Comment: @NickD: Could you make an example of how this would look like in detail?

Comment: @NickD: I changed the question slightly to allow an answer in this direction...

Answer (score 5):

Here's an answer to the modified question (keeping the table and the source code in the Org mode file). I've stolen the pandas part from [Quang Hoang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67064574/2561714):

```
* foo

Here's a table:

  #+NAME: foo
  |  a |   b |    c |
  |----+-----+------|
  |  1 |   1 |    1 |
  |  2 |   4 |    8 |
  |  3 |   9 |   27 |
  |  4 |  16 |   64 |
  |  5 |  25 |  125 |
  |  6 |  36 |  216 |
  |  7 |  49 |  343 |
  |  8 |  64 |  512 |
  |  9 |  81 |  729 |
  | 10 | 100 | 1000 |
#+TBLFM: $2=pow($1, 2) :: $3 = pow($1, 3)
```

Here's a source block that initializes the variable `tbl` with the table `foo` above
and does to it some pandas things as suggested by Quang Hoang in his answer.
To evaluate the code block, press `C-C C-c` in the code block.
You will then get the result below:

```
#+begin_src python :var tbl=foo :results output

    import pandas as pd

    D = pd.DataFrame(tbl).iloc[:, 1:-1]
    print(D)
#+end_src

  #+RESULTS:
  #+begin_example
       1
  0    1
  1    4
  2    9
  3   16
  4   25
  5   36
  6   49
  7   64
  8   81
  9  100
  #+end_example
```

See the [Org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Working-with-Source-Code.html#Working-with-Source-Code) for (*much*) more information about source blocks.

EDIT: To preserve the column names (the first row of the table), you can add `:colnames no` to the source block header. The column names themselves
are obtained inside the source block as `tbl[0]` and one can use that in the `DataFrame` constructor to label the columns as follows (n.b. In contrast to above, the `DataFrame` is the complete table. I just use a couple of different methods to select pieces of it to print out, including the `D.c` method you asked about in a comment):

```
  #+begin_src python :var tbl=foo :results output :colnames no

    import pandas as pd

    D = pd.DataFrame(tbl, columns=tbl[0])
    print(D.c)
    print("===========")
    print(D.iloc[1:, 0:-1])
  #+end_src

  #+RESULTS:
  #+begin_example
  0        c
  1        1
  2        8
  3       27
  4       64
  5      125
  6      216
  7      343
  8      512
  9      729
  10    1000
  Name: c, dtype: object
  ===========
       a    b
  1    1    1
  2    2    4
  3    3    9
  4    4   16
  5    5   25
  6    6   36
  7    7   49
  8    8   64
  9    9   81
  10  10  100
  #+end_example
```

Why `:colnames no` (and not `:colnames yes`) is needed to *add* the column names is something that I have never understood: one of these days, I should post a question on the Org mode mailing list about it...

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't seem to keep the column names. Any idea?

Comment: Try adding `:colnames no` to the source block header. As you might have surmised, I'm no pandas expert, so I'm not sure what needs to be done at what level. But if you are going to go this way, I would *strongly* encourage you to read the documentation (there's a lot of stuff there) and experiment.

Comment: Edited the answer to add the `:colnames` header.

Comment: I meant that I cannot refer to the column names inside of the source code block, for example by `D.d = D.a + D.b`.

Comment: Well, maybe this will help: inside the code block, `tbl[0]` is the first row, i.e. the column names: `['a', 'b', 'c']`. Now all you need to do is to somehow  tell pandas about them.

Comment: Edited again to add the access by column you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
D = pd.read_csv('file.dat', sep='\s*\|\s*').iloc[:, 1:-1]
```